# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on firmware (4.4.4)

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I have this app that works on 4.4.2 (AVD) and I tried to run it on a Nexus 4 (4.4.4), and on a Galaxy S3 (4.3) and i get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.mready.android.R$styleable
        at net.mready.android.widget.AbsoluteLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:154)
```

The file is located here:
app
   -> libs -> classes.jar -> net.mready.android.widget.AbsoluteLayout

Does anyone know what the problems is?

Btw, I'm using Android Studio 0.8.2 and when I click on the error, on the top of the file in the left part says "Sources not found" and in the right part "Attach Sources".

I tried to search here and I found some links but nothing works or I don't know how to follow them.

Comment: try to add multidex support in your application